# why i click the UISwitch , it not work?

Tags: ios, uiswitch

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        self.sw = [[[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(210, 8, 50, 30)] autorelease];
       [sw setOn:YES];
        [sw addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

       [self addSubview:sw];
    }

    return self;
}

-(void)switchChanged
{
    //    [self setImage];
    [sw setOn:NO];
    if (_delegate && [_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(selectedWith:)]){
        [_delegate selectedWith:self];
    }
}
```

when i click the switch ,but the function switchChanged not be called?

Comment: Irrelevant to your question but you shouldn't change the `isOn` property of `UISwitch` in `switchChanged`. It will handle it automatically.

Comment: UIControlEventTouchUpInside change this as below answers.Basically works in UIbutton.

Answer (score 1):

Change `forControlEvents` to **`UIControlEventValueChanged`** instead `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`

Try this,

```
 [sw addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the Event you specified should be  **UIControlEventValueChanged** when you need an action on changing the value in UISwitch

```
[sw addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
```